# ROS on roomba icreate

Tags: ros, roomba, installation, icreate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I plan to buy a roomba icreate to test out simple algorithms etc on it. I wish to know if ROS (diamondback/electric) is installable on roomba icreate. Any first hand experience would be most welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12203/ros-on-roomba-icreate/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes there are drivers and packages for the roomba icreate base. Actually one of the many supported robots, Turtlebot uses the roomba icreate base. But I assume you already know you would need a computer running a compatible OS in order to get things up and running. See this page for some ideas on installation http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation . And if your up to it you could assemble your own Turtlebot. Check out one of my favorite blog sites for some ideas on building your own turtlebot from scratch. http://profmason.com/?paged=2

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2011-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-12-04**:
@Atom : That 'make your own turtlebot' link is awesome ! ....

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also try some of the other stacks. Go to the [Browse Software](http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php) section on ROS and type roomba into the seach box and a couple other roomba stacks appear such as [lse_roomba_toolbox](http://ros.org/wiki/lse_roomba_toolbox) or [roomba_robot](http://ros.org/wiki/roomba_robot).

Have fun!

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-12-04**:
@Kevin : Cheers ! ..... nice profile pic ! ... :-D